# What Does "FrameTimeNanos" mean in "Choreographer.FrameCallback"? HW_VSYNC time or APP_VSYNC time?

Tags: android, vsync, surfaceflinger

I've read the source code of DispSync and so on, but it's too complicate.

What I've learnt is that "FrameCallback" is triggered by APP_VSYNC event, which may have time offset from HW_VSYNC. So, how could I know the precise time of HW_VSYNC?

If the time parameter of FrameCallback tells the APP_VSYNC time, where can I get the offset value between HW_VSYNC and APP_VSYNC so I can caculate the hardware vsync time?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the timestamps reported by Choreographer are the `APP_VSYNC` times.  As noted in the comments in Grafika's ScheduledSwapActivity:

```
* We coordinate with the display refresh using Choreographer.  The SurfaceFlinger DispSync
* enhancements may cause the Choreographer-reported vsync time to be offset from the
* actual-reported vsync time (which may itself be slightly offset from the actual-actual
* vsync time).  None of this is terribly important unless you care about A/V sync.
```

If A/V sync is your goal, you should probably be using the `setPresentationTime()` feature.  See the [comment above doFrame()](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ScheduledSwapActivity.java#L467) for additional notes.